# How can I list all my videos longer than 15 minutes in my Google+ Photo account?

Tags: google-plus

https://support.google.com/picasa/answer/6558?hl=en says:

> Google+ Photos: Only photos over 2048 x 2048 pixels and videos longer
>   than 15 minutes count towards your storage limit.

In order to make space in my account, I'd like to list all my videos longer than 15 minutes in my Google+ Photo account.