# How to find & delete Google+ photos larger than 2048px

Tags: google-plus-photos

A few months ago I enabled the "Full Size" upload option on my Google+ sync for photos. I then realized that I would soon run out of storage and I deselected the option, allowing a resizing to 2048px, which gives me "unlimited" storage (not really unlimited, but you get the point), as only photos over 2048 x 2048 pixels and videos longer than 15 minutes count towards your storage limit. [(doc. source)](https://support.google.com/picasa/answer/6558?hl=en)

I was at a healthy 7GB of storage, then today Google+ went completely crazy and said I was using 15.8GB of storage, and had to buy the 100GB option to be able to even send and receive emails.

I looked at the documentation online (BTW, it's totally broken and full of links that end up either nowhere or in the wrong place) and nowhere does it say how I can find the large files in my Google+ photo stream so that I can delete them.

I downloaded Picasa hoping that I could find those files from Google+, sort them by size, and delete from the Desktop app, but had no luck.

I don't want to keep paying for the 100GB (I really don't need them), and I'd like to find a way to identify the big files on Google+ so I can delete them and get back to the 7GB range.

Ideas?

Comment: By the same token: [How can I list all my videos longer than 15 minutes in my Google+ Photo account?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/58856/18147) ; [Program/extension/userscript software to find large videos in Google+](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3600/903)

Comment: [Free storage is 15GB](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/6558?hl=en&ref_topic=2375005), not 7GB

Comment: @abraham I know. Up to 15 is fine, so with 7 I well well within. I now have 15.8, so there is the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has now become straightforward:

- Go to: https://photos.google.com/u/0/settings
- Make sure "high quality" is checked (i.e., the compressed format which will deal with all future uploads)
- Click on the "Recover Storage" button then click "compress" (probably last thing before you go to bed)

When I did that, the next day my storage was down to tiny levels (presumably because all the photos in "original size" had been compressed). Job Done!

Comment: Great. I will give it a try. But before I do so: could I figure out what files will be recompressed, so I have a chance to backup them first?

Answer (score 1):

You can download all them. Delete all and upload them again (compressed to 2Mpx).

Unfortunately, the deletion can result in some side effects, about your current shares.

I done this in my account, but I deleted just the probable albums, which I suspected was uploaded at full size.